# Storing outbound Workflow emails

Tags: email, workflowoutboundmessage

Are there any specific functionality available from Salesforce to store outbound emails as a result of Work Flow execution?

Will using Compliance BCC Emails work to get inbound email to SFDC system and store it ?

Any ideas would be really thankful around this.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1 - Inbound Email Service**
The use of a bcc on the workflow email alert to an InboundEmailService is an excellent solution for this application to store the email.

You will probably want to be sure the email the recipient receives contains some sort of identifier that your inbound email service can parse to know where to attach the compliance copy.

**Option 2 - Custom Object**
Another alternative is to create the body of the email in Apex and save in a custom object which contains sufficient information to fire a workflow (field type = boolean: `is_ready__c`)and identify the recipients (field type = email : 'recipient1__c`,`recipient2__c`, ... )for use in the workflow's email alert.  I've used this approach when I needed to send emails upon update of a Task, but Task can't have associated workflows.